# How to set startup screen with options to open either windows or ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I installed Windows 10 after installing ubuntu. I have installed Windows 10 on different disk. But now I am not able to see ubuntu option on startup, windows 10 is by default opening. What should I do to repair grub or access ubuntu?

Comment: Which instructions did you follow to solve the problem?

Comment: This is a common problem when Windows 10 Upgrades, you know right? Windows 10 is updating every year with a "new version" of the operating system, so... I'm assuming that you computer upgraded to Creators Update and repaired the Windows Boot Manager, this is really easy to fix, just make a Ubuntu pendrive, boot it as a Live Session, opent a terminal and write :  `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` assuming that your disk is called `sda` you can confirm this with `lsblk` command, and voila, GRUB will now prompt when boot.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 and ubuntu both have different boot options as you installed windows after ubuntu(ubuntu uses GRUB boot loader),It alter the default boot options (i.e., GRUB for Ubuntu).

IF GRUB boot loader doesn't pop/show at booting.You can try this:-

Step 1: Boot windows 10

step 2: Open Command prompt (Run as Administrator).

step 3: Copy paste this code in command prompt(CMD) :-

`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

You don’t need to enter a password or anything like that.The command should run just fine given that your account has admin rights.

Step 4: Restart your computer and you’ll see a familiar Grub screen.Now choose your desired OS you want to boot.